# Gson - Exception while deserializing object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following object that I am trying to use Gson to serialize/deserialize:

```
public class ReportTemplate {

    private SimpleStringProperty templateName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private SimpleObjectProperty<ReportTemplate> destinationTemplate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    // The list of ReportColumns; holds the format as well
    private ArrayList<ReportColumn> columns;

    public ReportTemplate() {
    }

    public ReportTemplate(ArrayList<ReportColumn> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public String getTemplateName() {
        return templateName.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty templateNameProperty() {
        return templateName;
    }

    public void setTemplateName(String templateName) {
        this.templateName.set(templateName);
    }

    public ReportTemplate getDestinationTemplate() {
        return destinationTemplate.get();
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<ReportTemplate> destinationTemplateProperty() {
        return destinationTemplate;
    }

    public void setDestinationTemplate(ReportTemplate destinationTemplate) {
        this.destinationTemplate.set(destinationTemplate);
    }

    public List<ReportColumn> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(ArrayList<ReportColumn> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public ReportColumn getReportColumn(int index) {
        return columns.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return templateName.get();
    }
}
```

Running the following test code works perfectly fine:

```
class Test {

    private static ReportTemplate destinationFormat;
    private static ReportTemplate sourceFormat;
    private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> mappedColumns;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Template Lists
        ArrayList<ReportTemplate> sources = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ReportTemplate> dests = new ArrayList<>();

        ReportTemplate hiscox = new ReportTemplate(getSource());
        hiscox.setTemplateName("Hiscox");

        ReportTemplate agm = new ReportTemplate(getDestination());
        agm.setTemplateName("Monthly AGM");

        hiscox.setDestinationTemplate(agm);
        dests.add(agm);
        sources.add(hiscox);

        Global.setSourceTemplates(sources);
        Global.setDestinationTemplates(dests);

        TemplatesDatasource.saveTemplates(Global.getSourceTemplates());
        TemplatesDatasource.saveTemplates(Global.getDestinationTemplates());

        TemplatesDatasource.loadTemplates();

    }

    private static ArrayList<ReportColumn> getSource() {
        // Hiscox source format
        ArrayList<ReportColumn> sourceColumns = new ArrayList<>();
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Policy No.", 0, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Event Type", 1, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("New or Renewal", 2, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Insured Name", 3, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Display Date", 4, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Processed Date", 5, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Policy Effective Date", 6, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Policy Expiration Date", 7, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Premium", 8, ColumnFormat.CURRENCY));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Commission Rate", 9, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Commission", 10, ColumnFormat.CURRENCY));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("State", 11, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Partner", 12, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Partner Agent Name", 13, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Partner Agency Name", 14, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Partner Agent", 15, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Partner Agency Phone Number", 16, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Partner Agent Email", 17, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        sourceColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Partner Agent Representative", 18, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        return sourceColumns;
    }

    private static ArrayList<ReportColumn> getDestination() {
        // Destination format
        ArrayList<ReportColumn> destinationColumns = new ArrayList<>();
        destinationColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Agent Code", 0, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        destinationColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Agent Name", 1, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        destinationColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Agent Zip Code", 2, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        destinationColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Agent Email Address", 3, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        destinationColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Line of Business", 4, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        destinationColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Policy Number", 5, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        destinationColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Event Type", 6, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        destinationColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Insured Name", 7, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        destinationColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Premium", 8, ColumnFormat.CURRENCY));
        destinationColumns.add(new ReportColumn("Effective Date", 9, ColumnFormat.TEXT));
        return destinationColumns;
    }
}
```

Now, in my actual application, I use the `ReportTemplate` objects to populate various JavaFX controls (by converting them to `ObservableArrayList` when running the `setItems()` method; I do not alter the original list in any way.

When serializing the `ReportTemplate` objects back to JSON in my application, the output includes "helper" and "observable" keys. When trying to load those output files again, I get the following two exceptions:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Abstract class can't be instantiated! Class name: com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper<java.lang.String>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

Here is the code I use to save them from my application (which is identical to the above):

```
// save the Templates
        TemplatesDatasource.saveTemplates(Global.getSourceTemplates());
        TemplatesDatasource.saveTemplates(Global.getDestinationTemplates());
```

Within `Global`, the original source and destination template lists are not altered in any way after creating them with the `fromJson()` method in Gson.

I have spent several hours looking up various similar questions, but none seem to address why Gson is including extra keys in the output Json when it should be identical to the test output.

Could someone please suggest where my problem may lie?  I have been unable to duplicate the error in a smaller test project, so it obviously has something to do with my complete application, whose code is too large to post here.

Comment: Suggest you to put an example of code where it fails not where it succeeds. Smells like you have some `ExpressionHelper` nested, maybe in some extending `ReportTemplate` but hard to say without seeing the actual failing code. Maybe JavaFX  'enhances' the data used to populate components? In that case seems like a task for an `ExclusionStrategy` then.

Comment: It seems that you serialize the `ObservableArrayList` not the original `List`. Without knowing about JavaFX deeper. If you need to de-serialize also `helper` & `observable` you need some custom de-serializer, maybe.